# How to view Typeclass definitions and a type's Typeclass implementations

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

How can the definition of a Typeclass be viewed in ghci? For example, suppose I want to inspect the definition of `Eq` or `Num` from the terminal (not looking through source code files). Is there a way to achieve this?

Going one step further, how can the default implementation of a Typeclass be viewed for a type. For example, how can I view the way that `Double` implements `+` so as to satisfy part of the requirement to belong to `Num`?

One problem with the answer at the linked question (candidate for duplicate): The hoogle result for `data Double` does not include a link for source code the way that `Maybe` does in the example. So it still doesn't provide a way to see how a type implements a Typeclass.

If my question is very misguided, help in resolving my confusion is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe using `:info Eq`?

Comment: This says, "Defined in GHC.Classes" but it's not clear to me what that is or where to find it. It does give info on which types belong to Eq, but I'm looking for default implementations of the Typeclass's required functions. And what about the second question?

Comment: @EMS Are you wanting to view source code or view what instances are defined?  The source for `Double`'s implementation of `Num` probably won't help you as much as you might think, it's very low level since the `Double` type is a primitive in Haskell.  As for the default implementations, usually the documentation will tell you or you can view the source for the typeclass.  In the case of [`Num`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Num.html#Num), you can see that the default implementations for `negate` and `-` are defined in terms of each other.

Comment: Actually, it is that very low-level implementation I am looking for. One question that's been bothering me as I do things in Haskell is how do I get all the way down to where I can interact with bits for a type like Double. I feel that this is much more transparent in a language like C/C++, and figured somewhere in the default types it must be available in Haskell too.

Comment: (That's not to say it is a criticism of Haskell -- I realize the languages are different for a reason. But, it is still instructive to me to see how all the way down at the level of adding together two IEEE specified doubles, I can see what Haskell is doing.)

Comment: One problem with the answer at the other question: The hoogle result for `data Double` does *not* include a link for source code the way that `Maybe` does in the example. So it still doesn't provide a way to see how a type implements a Typeclass.

Comment: Viewing how stuff is _implemented_ is hardy GHCi's job! You want source code, so, well, you'll need to browse the source code.

Comment: For your stated goal--seeing how bits get moved around--the "duplicate" question isn't helpful, and I feel that other commenters are being coy. The "implementation" of `Double` is in [`GHC.Types`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.3.1.0/docs/src/GHC-Types.html#Double) and `GHC.Prim` in the same package. But you'll see that there's almost nothing there. The "real" implementation is of course in GHC itself.